# How to avoid loading cycle in Racket?

Tags: scheme, racket

I have quite simple set of `.rkt` sources and, say, "a.rkt" and "b.rkt" among them. I'd like to be able to write `(require "a.rkt")` in "b.rkt" and vice versa. Now I'm facing error about "loading cycle".

Can I solve this issue with bare modules without adding units? Does Racket have anything similar to forward declaration so I could simple add missing signature instead of requiring? If both answers are "No", does someone know good and understandable tutorial on how to implement units with `typed/racket` (*aside* of official docs)?

Comment: A cyclical dependency is _typically_ a code smell indicative of improper structuring of your program. Can you provide more details about your modules that might help us understand the _necessity_ of your requirement?

Comment: Sure, for example, I have some Engine and some Item, and Item has lambdas as fields and these lambdas take Engine object as first argument; later Engine is processing lists of Items. So Engine requires Item and Item requires Engine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`lazy-require`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/lazy-require.html):

```
;; a.rkt
#lang racket
(require racket/lazy-require)
(lazy-require ["b.rkt" (b)])
(provide a)
(define (a) 'a)
(list (a) (b))

;; b.rkt
#lang racket
(require racket/lazy-require)
(lazy-require ["a.rkt" (a)])
(provide b)
(define (b) 'b)
(list (a) (b))
```

Notice that you must tell `lazy-require` the specific things you want to import. That's because it is implemented in terms of `dynamic-require` plus `set!`.

If you peek at the [source for `xrepl`](https://github.com/racket/xrepl/blob/master/xrepl-lib/xrepl/xrepl.rkt#L29-L39), you'll see it define a `defautoload` macro, which (modulo some N/A details) is simply:

```
(define-syntax-rule (defautoload libspec id ...)
  (begin
    (define id
      (make-keyword-procedure
       (λ (kws kw-args . args)
         (set! id (dynamic-require 'libspec 'id))
         (keyword-apply id kws kw-args args))))
    ...))
```

Comment: Good, thank you! Do you know if there are any troubles using `lazy-require` with `typed/racket`?

Comment: Oh. That wasn't clear to me from your question. Yes, there are troubles. If you're using Typed Racket I suggest using units (or make a fresh question here about writing your own typed lazy-require) -- if you're certain you really need mutually `require`-ing modules. But first: Check if you can use recursive definitions of Engine and/or Item with [`define-type`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/special-forms.html#(form._((lib._typed%2Fracket%2Fbase..rkt)._define-type)))? And/or use a "defs.rkt" or "types.rkt" that the other files `require`.

Comment: Thank you very much, Greg. Now I understand that in different language I would try to use interfaces or traits. But this is quite different topic.