# Racket: forward declaration of an interface

Tags: interface, scheme, racket

If I have two interfaces defined side by side and I'd like to have references of each one in another one inside contracts, i.e.:

```
(define context-interface<%>
  (interface ()
    [entity-list (->m (listof (is-a?/c entity-interface<%>)))]
    )
  )

(define entity-interface<%>
  (interface ()
    [on-add (->m (is-a?/c context-interface<%>) void?)]
    )
```

what should I do to avoid `cannot reference an identifier before its definition` error? I haven't found anything like forward declaration in C++ meaning in Racket docs. From the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52210511/1840136) for my previous question I know that it is possible to somehow solve issue using `lazy-require`, but what if I want to keep both definitions in same source file?

Comment: This documentation for [_Defining Recursive Contracts_](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/contracts-gotchas.html#(part._.Defining_.Recursive_.Contracts)) might help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this kind of "value not initialized" error in recursive contracts by adding [`recursive-contract`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/contract-utilities.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fcontract%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._recursive-contract%29%29) around a part of the contract, to delay that part's evaluation until it's needed. In this case, you can add [`recursive-contract`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/contract-utilities.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fcontract%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._recursive-contract%29%29) around `(is-a?/c entity-interface<%>)`.

```
(define context-interface<%>
  (interface ()
    [entity-list (->m (listof (recursive-contract (is-a?/c entity-interface<%>))))]
    ))

(define entity-interface<%>
  (interface ()
    [on-add (->m (is-a?/c context-interface<%>) void?)]
    ))
```

Note that it can be around `(is-a?/c entity-interface<%>)` because that's a contract value, but it cannot be around just `entity-interface<%>` because that's a racket/class interface value and not a contract.

Comment: Great! I see that it may be `(recursive-contract (->m (listof (is-a?/c trait-interface<%>)))` as well, but currently I don't understand if it will make any difference in terms of, for example, performance. 

And isn't it some kind of abuse of `recursive-contract` as it was (as I understand) created for definition recursion purposes?

Comment: No, it's not an abuse of `recursive-contract`. The `recursive-contract` adds extra laziness, so the performance implications are probably similar to lazy promises or streams, but I don't know for certain