# How to avoid cycle loading in Typed Racket

Tags: module, racket, typed-racket

consider a common situation,
a.rkt

```
#lang typed/racket
(require "b.rkt")
(struct A ([a-b : B]))
(provide (struct-out A))
```

b.rkt

```
#lang typed/racket
(require "a.rkt")
(struct B ([b-a : A]))

(provide (struct-out B))
```

it will crush when `racket a.rkt` because cycle loading,but we just require b.rkt for type checking,
as in python it would solved by

```py
if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
    import B
```

Is there any similar solution in typed racket like python?Or just types that contains each other must written in one file because limitation?

Two types in different typed racket module could reference to each other

Comment: This [racket question is related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52137060/how-to-avoid-loading-cycle-in-racket) and a comment in the answer mentions typed racket

Comment: In general avoiding circular dependencies is a good idea in any language

Comment: tried some solution from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52137060/how-to-avoid-loading-cycle-in-racket), there is not typed racket version `lazy-require` I can't use lazy-require in typed racket, also tried unit, seems it could not help with module cycle load, still must define two unit signature in one module (file) @Sylwester

Comment: I was taught so, but I do need cycle reference in some situation, and I could do this in TypeScript even python which strongly not again cycle import (by if typing.TYPE_CHECK ) @Shawn

Comment: Even if you put both structure definitions in the same module, it is impossible to ever make an instance of either one.  That, together with the circularity, is probably telling you something.